# View Change in SwiftUi Using Enum

Tags: swiftui, enums, view, state

I have multiple views in a swift project I am trying to change Views My idea is to make an enum, and change state. I do not want to use navigationLinks.
Here is my code:

```
struct NightOutApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
         WindowGroup {
             ViewNavigator()
        }
    }
}
```

```
enum ViewState{
    case LoginView
    case UserProfileView
    
}
```

```
struct ViewNavigator: View {
    var body: some View {
        @State var ViewState = ViewState.LoginView
        return Group{
            switch ViewState{
                case .LoginView:
                LoginView()
                case .UserProfileView:
                    UserProfileView()
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

I have a variable
`@Binding var ViewState: ViewState` at the top of the LoginView
some logic on the LoginView that would change ViewState from LoginView to UserProfileView:

`self.ViewState = .UserProfileView`

I tried using binding variables. this gave me a warning: Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update.

Edit-
Here is what happens when I run it. I press a button to login, It takes me to this breakpoint. The code seems to process, but the view does not change.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH2LF.png)

Comment: Can you show your attempt? This sounds like it should work, but something just went wrong.

Comment: I attached a screenshot to the original post

Comment: Can you include code in the form of a [mre]? That screenshot is not copy and pastable, runnable, etc

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've edited my answer in an attempt to understand what you're looking for. It seems you are needing a login flow but I don't think I can understand your problem fully without seeing more of your code. Here is an example that you should be able to copy and paste and play around with while you figure out exactly what you're needing.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ViewNavigator: View {
    @State var viewState = 0
    @State var withEmail: String = ""
    @State var withPassword: String = ""
    
    @State var showAlert: Bool = false
    @State var alertTitle: String = ""
    @State var alertMessage: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            switch viewState {
            case 0:
                loginView
            case 1:
                profileView
            default:
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                bottomButton
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .alert(alertTitle, isPresented: $showAlert) {  } message: {
            Text(alertMessage)
        }
    }
    
    func handleBottomButtonPressed() {
        switch viewState {
        case 0:
            guard !withEmail.isEmpty else {
                showAlert(title: "Wait!", message: "Your email is required.")
                return
            }
            guard withPassword == "password"  else {
                showAlert(title: "Hold Up!", message: "Your password is incorrect.")
                return
            }
         default:
            break
        }
        
        if viewState == 0 {
            viewState += 1
            withPassword = ""
        } else {
            viewState -= 1
        }
    }
    
    func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        alertTitle = title
        alertMessage = message
        showAlert.toggle()
    }
    
}

struct ViewNavigator_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewNavigator()
    }
}

extension ViewNavigator {
    private var bottomButton: some View {
        Button {
            handleBottomButtonPressed()
        } label: {
            Text(viewState == 0 ? "LOGIN" : "LOGOUT")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
        }
    }
    
    
    private var loginView: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "1.square")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                Text("LOGIN")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                VStack {
                    TextField("email...", text: $withEmail)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray5))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                    SecureField("password...", text: $withPassword)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray5))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var profileView: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "2.square")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                Text("Profile View")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *edited after OP's edit